# Does the TSA allow liquids based on the US or Metric measurements?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, tsa

I have a bottle of hair styling gel that says is it 3.59 oz (100 ml). The TSA allows you to have 3.4 oz (100 ml) liquid containers.  The people who made my gel incorrectly converted one way or the other. Will they allow it since it is 100 ml or disallow it since it says 3.59 oz?

Comment: It could go either way. If you don't want to risk losing it, check it or leave it at home.

Comment: Put a sticker over the "3.59" so that only "100 ml" is visible. Sorted.

Comment: Bear in mind that the US [uses a different size fluid ounce from everyone else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_ounce).  That given, I submit it is even more likely that as long as the container is clearly labelled as 100ml or less, and otherwise compliant, it will pass inspection.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of telling really. If the bottle looks too big, they'll discard it. If it looks like around 100 ml, the official will look at the contents labeled on the container.

My metric European mind says they'll look at the 100 ml (easier to distinguish) but when you've lived with US [fluid ounces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_ounce) all your life you might as well have 3.4 burned into your mind (not the 3.59 *imperial* fluid ounce). So in that case seeing 3.59 will be reason for dismissal.

Once a TSA officer has made a decision they generally don't bargain. Specifically not about containers not being full. They *may* be sensible to that, but don't count on it.

So, as Michael hampton commented:
*Put a sticker over the "3.59" so that only "100 ml" is visible. Sorted.*
Or leave the container at home.
Or take a smaller travel bottle and put in what you expect to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well TSA is a US agency so they'll be going my Imperial sizing. But they're not SUPER crazy checking the exact volume of bottles. My rule of thumb is basically is it bigger than a bottle of hotel shampoo? Anything about that size is A-OK. Yes its smaller than 100mL usually but its a safe bet it will travel. Also if it's sold in the travel section of a drug store, it's a good bet it will travel.

Also helpful tip, put all those liquids and gels into a clear ziplock back and put it through separately at security. Makes it easier for them and they get less picky. The easier you make their job the easier they are on you... generally.

Comment: Also, **not** Imperial sizing at all: see my comment above, the US fluid ounce is a different size from the Imperial one!